# How to only display a certain area on Google Maps IOS API

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am working on a project and I need to know if I can utilize google maps to only view a certain area. For example only my town, is there any way of restricting the map?

I have heard of using bounds but I cant seem to find the Docs for it for ios

Comment: please help still no clue

Comment: are you asking whether you can turn off the zoom/pan of the map?